# Why shouldn't I return HTML from an ASP.NET ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, owin

Looking at tutorials for self-hosted OWIN apps, the tutorials all point to using an ApiController. This code works:

```
public class MapController : ApiController
{
    // Get /map
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage>  Get()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            string html = File.ReadAllText("./Client/html/MapExample.html");
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StringContent(html)
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

And this seems to work... Why would I want to extend `Controller` vs `ApiController`?

I actually don't have access to the `Controller` class so far as I can tell with the OWIN libraries...

Comment: Why are you using a task here?

Comment: @mason, just because I don't know any better. My thinking was that I want the file io to be asynchronous. Is that correct? What would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: Don't pre-optimize. It's bad. If performance wasn't an issue, now you've just made your code more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks. If I did want to load the file asynchronously, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Again, it sounds like you want to pre-optimize. Just don't. Async doesn't magically solve things. It'd make far more sense to read the HTML for your views into memory on application bootup, that way you don't need to do disc access each time you need to return some HTML.

Comment: I will definitely do that. I come from a node.js background and am wondering if I've been using async correctly in c#

Comment: Probably haven't been using it correctly - async is not easy to wrap your head around. I would just avoid it in C# until it's absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, there is nothing wrong with returning Html from an API Controller.

The only reason you wouldn't want to do that is because the convention is that API Controllers are used for exposing Service Functionality and ASP.NET MVC Controllers are used for serving up Web Sites or Pages.

Therefore, some developers will be confused by this approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to asp.net and have been trying to read up on owin. All the tutorials use apicontroller.